# Bootstrap 4 filterable select (dropdown)

Tags: bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I have a Spring / Thymeleaf / Bootstrap 4 project I'm working in. And I'm trying to do something similar to https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_filters_dropdown&stacked=h

So, I did the following:

```
<div id="updateUser">
<select data-th-field="*{userId}"
        data-th-style="|width: 300px; max-width: 300px;|"
        class="form-control ml-2"
        aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
   <input class="form-control" id="userFilter" type="text">
   <option data-th-value="-1" text=""></option>
   <option data-th-each"user: ${userList}" 
           data-th-value="${user.id}"
           data-th-text="${user.getDisplayNameForDropdown()"></option>
</select>
</div>

<script data-th-inline="javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  $(document).ready(function() {
    ...
    filterUsers();
  })

  function filterUser() {
    $("#userFilter").on("keyup", function() {
      let value - $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      $("#updateUser option").filter(function() {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
      });
    });
  }
  //]]>
```

Without the input, the select works fine and all the option elements appear and disappear like a dropdown is supposed to act.  With the input field in the way, the select box appears, but does not toggle, and the input field appears below the select, and all my user names appear below the input box.  The nice thing is the filter does work with the input field.

I just don't know how to get the input field and options to open and close with the select click.